# keep value after page refresh in React

Tags: reactjs

Actually, I passed dropdown value in the URL, but how to show the selected value after the page refresh? please solve this issue. I want to try when user select any option then value show on url and after page refresh same selected value show .Thank you

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Link ,navigate} from "gatsby";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("black");
  const Vdata = [{
  title:"black"
  },
    {
    title:'red'
    }]
  const handleChange = (value) => {
     
     setData(value);
     navigate(`/?location=${value}`);
   };

 
  return (
    <div className="grid place-items-center">
      <select
        value={data}
        autocomplete="off"
        name=""
        id=""
        className="border p-2 shadow-xl"
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target.value)}
      >
        {Vdata.map((i) => (
          <option value={i.title} selected>
            {i.title}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <p>{window.location.href}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

// export default IndexPage
```

Comment: if your project is gonna grow, which it will, why not use react redux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Window localStorage** object allows you to save key/value pairs in the browser.
[detail info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Initiate data with localStorage stored info, if null default set "black"

```
const [data, setData] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('title')) || "black";
```

Add useEffect function to store this selected value when set data.

```
  const handleChange = (value) => {
     setData(value);
     navigate(`/?location=${value}`);
   };

  React.useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('title', JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data]);
```

Finally, `Vdata.map((i) => (` should add some condition to set `selected` attribute.

Comment: hello sir, may I store on URl ? without using  localStorage. actually when i open this link  another browser  selected value changed.

Comment: localStorage is persistent across pages in the same domain. So you don't need use URL way.